# Is it okay to override a conflict generated during `rails new first_app`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`$ cd rails_projects`
`$ rails new first_app`

I got this conflict at the bottom of the output below: `conflict  config/initializers/secret_token.rb`

```
       exist  
   identical  README.rdoc
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  config.ru
   identical  .gitignore
   identical  Gemfile
       exist  app
   identical  app/assets/images/rails.png
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
   identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
   identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
       exist  app/mailers
       exist  app/models
   identical  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
   identical  app/mailers/.gitkeep
   identical  app/models/.gitkeep
       exist  config
   identical  config/routes.rb
   identical  config/application.rb
   identical  config/environment.rb
       exist  config/environments
   identical  config/environments/development.rb
   identical  config/environments/production.rb
   identical  config/environments/test.rb
       exist  config/initializers
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
    conflict  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
Overwrite /Users/XXXXXX/rails_projects/first_app/config/initializers/secret_token.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh]
```

What does  `config/initializers/secret_token.rb` do? I ran this before and overrode the code and got the bundle to install, but wanted to know if there are unintended consequences.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie based sessions in Ruby use the secret token to guarantee cookies are created with a secret string, and can't be easily re-created.

Changing the secret token won't affect anything, unless you change it on production while having users logged in, which will cause them to get logged off as they won't be recognized to have a valid cookie that matches your token.

If you wanted to generate a new secret token, you could simply run:

```
rake secret
```

(or, you could simply generate a long string yourself if you fancied)

Be weary though that it's important to keep this file away from any open source repository, as by having access to it, people could hijack sessions on your Rails website

More about it [Reminder: secret_token.rb is named so for a reason.](http://biggestfool.tumblr.com/post/24049554541/reminder-secret-token-rb-is-named-so-for-a-reason)

HTH

**UPDATE**

Also, if you want to read more, there's an excellent documentation article about it [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html)